# Module Development in DNN 7.00.04

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I was reading a DNN manual called 'DotNetNuke Module Developers Guide' for developing new modules from scratch. 
The manual says to create a class library project and add reference to DotNetNuke project.

I do not find any such project in Community version source code for version 7.00.04. However, I can see DotNetNuke.Web and DotNetNuke.Web.WebClient projects but none that is called DotNetNuke.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a DNN project, but there is a DotNetNuke.dll, add a reference to that (the project I believe is DotNetNuke.Library)

I would also suggest taking a look at my Templates for DNN, they make doing module development easy http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

Comment: Chris - Thanks for the answer. That helped. I actually tried your template, but it never worked for me. So that is why I decided to learn modules building in a more fundamental manner. I am following an article in code-magazine at http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0407061&page=6

Comment: When I use the template, it says that I don't have IIS web server and use IIS express instead and that it cannot create a configuration file.

Comment: Daniel, please start a new Question if you are having trouble with the templates